# Facebook Login issue when facebook app is installed in android

Tags: android, facebook

Hi I am using Facebook login in my app and I have following issues..

When there is no native facebook app is installed in phone, every thing is working fine and I am able to get the userInfo.

But if facebook app is installed, and when I try to login to facebook in my app, after logging in it is always going to session.isClosed() method every time.

I was not able to get the data and no control on app after that.

Is there any cache managment required to solve this? IF yes how to do that?

Comment: Please check the "exception" field in your StatusCallback. If your session is transitioning to closed, it usually means an error occurred (and it's usually your key hash not being set up properly).

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855517/android-facebook-login-not-working-with-installed-facebook-app

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use

```
loginButton.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```

or

```
Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Sesion.OpenRequest(activity);
openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
```